# PHP - copy certain array from multidimensional array to another new array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => c [3] =>a [4] => ) 

[1] => Array ( [0] => c [1] => a [2] => d [3] => [4] => ) 

[2] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => a [3] => [4] => )

[3] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => d [2] => c [3] =>b [4] => )

)
```

and was wondering whether I can copy all inner array from it to another array where the first element is "b" so it looks like. Will the new array be reindexed when created? Thank you.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => c [3] =>a [4] => ) 

[1] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => a [3] => [4] => )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Had a little error in my code. Now it is fixed and working if you still need it.

```
$firstArray = array (array ('b', 'd', 'c', 'a'), 
                     array ('c', 'd', 'a', 'b'), 
                     array ('b', 'd', 'a', 'c'), 
                     array ('a', 'd', 'c', 'b'));

$secondArray = array();

foreach($firstArray as $sub) {

    if($sub[0] == 'b') {

        $secondArray[] = $sub;
    }
}

print_r($secondArray);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => c [3] => a ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d [2] => a [3] => c ) )
```

Comment: I was using: foreach($firstArray as $sub=>$value) and was checking for $value[0] instead of $sub[0], as well as $secondArray[] = $sub[0]; and was saving just the first element!  $sub is really the full array! Doh! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
function check($val) {
     return ($val[0] == 'b');
}
$secondArray = array_filter($firstArray, "check");
```